# changing varchar2 data type in oracle due to more size requirement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, plsql

I am using one application in which I am using `jdbc`. as of now we have input length in UI for user is `320000` (320k). so we were dividing this field in 10 parts and sending this to `Pl/SQL` db procedure to insert into the table. We were receiving message in 10 varchar2 variables in procedure parameter.

But now client has changed the requirement. and he want to double the size for user.
so if we divide `640000/10` it will come `64000` which goes beyond the limit of `varchar2` which is 32767. means we can not use varchar2 type variable in procedure to store these values.

This procedure is called by many other applications.

My question is which datatype should I change for my `pl/sql` variables inside procedure instead of `varchar2` so that code does not break for other applications?

existing is

```
create procedure(field 1 varchar2, field2 varchar2...........field10 varchar2)
begin

end
```

what datatype we should use instead of varchar2 here.

In procedure we are aggregating these inputs and storing into one single column which is of CLOB type.

I read the documentation but still did not get solution

Comment: Your number `3,20000` is presented in a very strange format. Do you mean `3,200,000`? Or just `320,000`?

Comment: Why are you not just using a single CLOB argument - why split it in to shorter strings at all?

Comment: It was done long back by some other developers....I am not so sure Alex. is there any solution looking at existing setup.

Answer (score 1):

If there is a possibility for you to split the data in 2 sets of 10 fields of VarChar2(32000) values - you could, in that case (with minor intervention), keep your procedure working.
What I'm trying to say is that you split first 320K in ten fields like you already do - put them into an array and then take the second set of 320K data using the same logic. In that case you should in your original procedure add one more parameter saying if it is set no. 1 or 2.
You should handle the proces with a small package and an array.
Not sure how your procedure looks like, just offering something to think about.
Here is an option - 1st create an array of the appropriate size:

```sql
create or replace TYPE X_ARRAY 
AS VARRAY(32) OF VarChar2(32000);
```

Next is the package to handle the data and to get you a CLOB to be written into a database:

```sql
create or replace PACKAGE MANAGE_CLOBS AS 
-- -----------------------------------------------  
  Procedure Init;
-- -----------------------------------------------
  Procedure AddPart(p_Part IN VARCHAR2);
-- ----------------------------------------------
  Function GetArray RETURN X_ARRAY;
-- ----------------------------------------------
  Function GetCLOB RETURN CLOB;
-- ----------------------------------------------
  Procedure SetToArray(P_FIELD1 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD2 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD3 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD4 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD5 IN VARCHAR2, 
                       P_FIELD6 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD7 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD8 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD9 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD10 IN VARCHAR2, P_SET_NUMBER IN NUMBER := 1);
--
END MANAGE_CLOBS;
```

... and package body ...

```sql
create or replace PACKAGE BODY MANAGE_CLOBS AS
    mSet      NUMBER(1);
    mArray    X_ARRAY;
    mCLOB     CLOB;
  -- -----------------------------------------------  
    Procedure Init IS
        Begin
            mSet := 0;
            mArray := X_ARRAY();
             mCLOB := Null;
        End Init;
  -- -----------------------------------------------
    Procedure AddPart(P_Part IN VARCHAR2) is
        Begin
            mCLOB := mCLOB || P_Part;
        End AddPart;
  -- ---------------------------------------------
    Function GetArray RETURN X_ARRAY IS
        BEGIN
            RETURN mArray;
        END GetArray;
  -- ---------------------------------------------
    Function GetCLOB RETURN CLOB IS
        BEGIN
            FOR i In 1..mArray.count LOOP
                AddPart(mArray(i));
            END LOOP;
            RETURN mCLOB;
        END GetCLOB;
-- ---------------------------------------------
    Procedure SetToArray(P_FIELD1 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD2 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD3 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD4 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD5 IN VARCHAR2, 
                         P_FIELD6 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD7 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD8 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD9 IN VARCHAR2, P_FIELD10 IN VARCHAR2, P_SET_NUMBER IN NUMBER := 1) IS
            idx   Number(2);
            fld   VarChar2(32000);
            sq    VarChar2(1) := '''';
        BEGIN
            If mSet < P_SET_NUMBER Then
                mSet := P_SET_NUMBER;
                mArray.extend;
                mArray((P_SET_NUMBER - 1) * 10 + 1) := P_FIELD1;
                mArray.extend;
                mArray((P_SET_NUMBER - 1) * 10 + 2) := P_FIELD2;
                mArray.extend;
                mArray((P_SET_NUMBER - 1) * 10 + 3) := P_FIELD3;
                mArray.extend;
                mArray((P_SET_NUMBER - 1) * 10 + 4) := P_FIELD4;
                mArray.extend;
                mArray((P_SET_NUMBER - 1) * 10 + 5) := P_FIELD5;
                mArray.extend;
                mArray((P_SET_NUMBER - 1) * 10 + 6) := P_FIELD6;
                mArray.extend;
                mArray((P_SET_NUMBER - 1) * 10 + 7) := P_FIELD7;
                mArray.extend;
                mArray((P_SET_NUMBER - 1) * 10 + 8) := P_FIELD8;
                mArray.extend;
                mArray((P_SET_NUMBER - 1) * 10 + 9) := P_FIELD9;
                mArray.extend;
                mArray((P_SET_NUMBER - 1) * 10 + 10) := P_FIELD10;
            End If;
        END SetToArray;
END MANAGE_CLOBS;
```

Now your procedure that collects the data from 10 (32000) fields should be altered to something like below, where you would pass your FIELD1, FIELD2,... , FIELD10 data in two sets (the last parameter). The data will be stored in the array and after that collected into xCLOB variable that you can store in your table.

```sql
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare 
    xArray    X_ARRAY;
    xCLOB     CLOB;
Begin
    MANAGE_CLOBS.Init;
    MANAGE_CLOBS.SetToArray('AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC', 'DDDDD', 'EEEEE',
                           'FFFFF', 'GGGGG', 'HHHHH', 'IIIII', 'JJJJJ', 1);
    --
    MANAGE_CLOBS.SetToArray('kkkkk', 'lllll', 'mmmmm', 'nnnnn', 'ooooo',
                           'ppppp', 'rrrrr', 'sssss', 'ttttt', 'uuuuu', 2);
    --
    xArray := MANAGE_CLOBS.GetArray;  -- this line is not needed - here it is just for you to do some cheks if you want before transfer to xCLOB
    xCLOB := MANAGE_CLOBS.GetCLOB;    -- xCLOB should contain all the data passed to the procedure
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SubStr(xCLOB, 1, 200));
End;
--  
--  R e s u l t :
--  anonymous block completed
--  AAAAABBBBBCCCCCDDDDDEEEEEFFFFFGGGGGHHHHHIIIIIJJJJJkkkkklllllmmmmmnnnnnoooooppppprrrrrssssstttttuuuuu
```

Regards...

Answer (score -1):

Oracle LONG type can hold up to 2GB, so 2G single byte characters or 1G Unicode characters.